# Как исключить повторное значение из цикла php?

Tags: php, mysql, циклы, while

Всем привет. Я публикую данные из бд mysql в php с помощью цикла. Но иногда эти данные повторяются. Как убрать вывод повторных данных?

Мой код выглядит так:

Выбираю данные из mysql

```
$buy_info = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM
    `dress`
WHERE
    price = (SELECT MIN(`price`) FROM `dress` WHERE `color` LIKE '%blue%' AND `size` = '52')");
```

Запускаю цикл

```
while ($pay_buy = mysqli_fetch_assoc($buy_info)){    
echo $pay_buy['seller_name'];
echo $pay_buy['price'];
}
```

Выводятся данные такого формата:

> Имя продавца: Хенкок. Цена: 1054

Но иногда встречается этот же продавец и получается что-то вроде того:

> Имя продавца: Хенкок. Цена: 1054
> Имя продавца: Хенкок. Цена: 1054
> Имя продавца: Хенкок. Цена: 1054

Вопрос. Как сделать исключение? Если строка с именем этого продавца уже выводилась, то не выводить заново?

Comment: добавьте  distinct в селест

Comment: Получилось, спасибо!

Comment: Хотя нет... так получается фильтровать имена. То есть echo $pay_buy['seller_name']; работает, а цена в таком случае уже не выводится... Я сделал так "SELECT DISTINCT `seller_name` FROM... Может неправильно?

Comment: получилось, если проставить названия всех столбцов, кроме id. Громоздко, но работает

Comment: Грубо говоря, так: "SELECT DISTINCT seller_name, price FROM...